# Top bar is visible through 'welcome back' message

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: top bar is visible through 'welcome back' message]

`.top-bar { z-index: 5050; }` versus `#overlay-header { z-index: 5052; }` so the overlay should win. Strangely enough disabling the top bar z-index fixes the issue. Another fix is to set the overlay background alpha to 1 instead of 0.95

So maybe a combination of the z-index and alpha is responsible for this?

Using Firefox 67.0.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: The "welcome back" banner has been implemented since SE's early years and that code has never been touched in a while.

Comment: This has been fixed.